# Serving an API connected to mssql SQL Server using NUXT's integrated Express framework

Tags: sql-server, api, express, nuxt.js

I've got a basic NUXT app running, and during setup I opted to include the integrated Express Server.

I managed to get my SQL server database connected to Express (including Windows Authentication yah!)

I'm struggling to get the url to return data though.  Using postman to hit the endpoint returns nuxt's built in 404 error page.

How do I configure NUXT to return the data from my query instead?

**nuxt.config.js**

```
const colors = require('vuetify/es5/util/colors').default

module.exports = {
  mode: 'universal',
  /*
   ** Headers of the page
   */
  head: {
    titleTemplate: '%s - ' + process.env.npm_package_name,
    title: process.env.npm_package_name || '',
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      {
        hid: 'description',
        name: 'description',
        content: process.env.npm_package_description || ''
      }
    ],
    link: [{ rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' }]
  },
  /*
   ** Customize the progress-bar color
   */
  loading: { color: '#fff' },
  /*
   ** Global CSS
   */
  css: [],
  /*
   ** Plugins to load before mounting the App
   */
  plugins: [],
  /*
   ** Nuxt.js dev-modules
   */
  buildModules: [
    // Doc: https://github.com/nuxt-community/eslint-module
    '@nuxtjs/eslint-module',
    '@nuxtjs/vuetify'
  ],
  /*
   ** Nuxt.js modules
   */
  modules: [
    // Doc: https://axios.nuxtjs.org/usage
    '@nuxtjs/axios'
  ],
  /*
   ** Axios module configuration
   ** See https://axios.nuxtjs.org/options
   */
  axios: {},
  /*
   ** vuetify module configuration
   ** https://github.com/nuxt-community/vuetify-module
   */
  vuetify: {
    customVariables: ['~/assets/variables.scss'],
    theme: {
      dark: true,
      themes: {
        dark: {
          primary: '#007B5F',
          accent: '#007FA3',
          secondary: '#33957F',
          info: colors.teal.lighten1,
          warning: colors.amber.base,
          error: colors.deepOrange.accent4,
          success: colors.green.accent3
        }
      }
    }
  },
  /*
   ** Build configuration
   */
  build: {
    /*
     ** You can extend webpack config here
     */
    extend(config, ctx) {}
  }
}
```

*These files are inside the root server folder*

**index.js**

```
const express = require('express')
const consola = require('consola')
const { Nuxt, Builder } = require('nuxt')

const app = express()

// Import and Set Nuxt.js options
const config = require('../nuxt.config.js')
config.dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'

// Add api routes
const bridgeRoute = require('./routes/bridgeRoute')

async function start() {
  // Init Nuxt.js
  const nuxt = new Nuxt(config)

  const { host, port } = nuxt.options.server

  // Build only in dev mode
  if (config.dev) {
    const builder = new Builder(nuxt)
    await builder.build()
  } else {
    await nuxt.ready()
  }

  // Give nuxt middleware to express
  app.use(nuxt.render)

  // Use included routes
  app.use('/api', bridgeRoute)

  // Listen the server
  app.listen(port, host)
  consola.ready({
    message: `Server listening on http://${host}:${port}`,
    badge: true
  })
}
start()
```

**db.js**

```
const sql = require('mssql/msnodesqlv8')
const consola = require('consola')
const dbConfig = require('./dbConfig')

// Swap between 'LOCAL', 'TEST' and 'PRODUCTION' environments
const connString = dbConfig.dbConfig.LOCAL.connectionString

const poolPromise = new sql.ConnectionPool(connString)
  .connect()
  .then((pool) => {
    consola.success('Connected to MSSQL')
    return pool
  })
  .catch((err) =>
    consola.error('Database Connection Failed! Bad Config: ', err)
  )

module.exports = {
  sql,
  poolPromise
}
```

*dbConfig just houses the connection string to connect to SQL Server*

**/routes/bridgeRoute.js**

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const { poolPromise } = require('../db')

router.get('api/bridges', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const pool = await poolPromise
    const result = await pool.request().query('SELECT TOP 10 FROM [BRIDGE]')

    res.json(result)
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500)
    res.send(err.message)
  }
})

module.exports = router
```